# User no longer appears in greeter after UID change (14.04)

Tags: login, lightdm

I've hunted around for solutions to this but to no avail.

I've changed my UID to 501 in order to access files on a drive pulled from my old Mac (HFS+). Now I can access the drive with no problems, but my user account no longer appears in the greeter nor in 'User Accounts' in the GUI.

As my system appears to use Accounts Service, the advice seems to be to change `UID_MIN` to 500 in `/etc/login.defs`, but I've done this to no avail. Is there anything else I need to change?

I've also changed the GID from 1000 to 501, and `GID_MIN` to 500 in `/etc/login.defs`, in case Accounts Service needed them to match for some reason.

From what I can gather, modifying `/etc/login.defs` seems to be the correct solution, but it hasn't worked for me.

Many thanks in advance,
Fraser